# Extracting and dumping elements using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am looking for a way to extract and print an element from my xml using xmlstarlet; for example if my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I would like to print out book element with price = 29.99 as:

```
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

I understand the xpath query to select such an element (/bookstore/book[price=29.99]) but
I am not able to print/dump it on stdout. If I use the '-v' option and use -v (.) I don't get the output as I want (with all the tags in it) I just get the text values. There ought to be a way to simply dump selected element as it is, and that's what I am looking for.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the "-c" (copy) option, should achieve what you're after:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/bookstore/book[price=29.99]" books.xml

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

You can watch the XSLT generated internally in xmlstarlet by adding the global "-C" switch after "sel". This shows how the copy option results in an xslt copy-of construct:

```
...
<xsl:template name="t1">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/bookstore/book[price=29.99]"/>
</xsl:template>
...
```

This results in namespace nodes, child nodes, and attributes nodes being included, cf. the XSLT spec [(see w3schools summary)](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp).

Comment: Had to change a number of characters, to escape SO 6 character minimum change limit. wouldn't work for me unless I put the @ in front of the attribute, i.e. @price=29.99 rather than price=29.99

Comment: Thanks.. i spent a almost a month looking for this -c switch.