# xmlstarlet: how to select element by alphanumeric content

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

[Extracting and dumping elements using xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890690/extracting-and-dumping-elements-using-xmlstarlet)

In this post I've found out, how to select element by its content.
Works perfectly!

But no for every value :-(

Here my xml:

```
<metainfo id="19120454-8234-47EB-B7FE-7691B53788DF" type="volume">
                <id>
                        3138224245
                </id>
                <index>
                        1
                </index>
                <is-last>
                        1
                </is-last>
                <name>
                        asdf
                </name>
                <raw-archive-id>
                        6898476220317415805
                </raw-archive-id>
                <raw-archive-key>
                        977D7B4B-D234-4E95-8BE2-BE0F8E865701
                </raw-archive-key>
                <size>
                        54812566016
                </size>
                <slice-key/>
                <timestamp>
                        1385742689568
                </timestamp>
        </metainfo>
```

Selecting by id, index or timestamp works perfectly.
("xml" is the command in the windows version ...):

```
xml sel -t -c "/metabundle/metainfo[timestamp=1385742689568]" test.xml
```

But something goes wrong if I want to select by another tag, for example "name" or "raw-archive-key":

```
xml sel -t -c "/metabundle/metainfo[name=asdf]" test.xml
```

This command will not produce any output.
In both tags, name and raw-archive-key, there are alphanumeric characters.
If I change "asdf" to "01", it works!

So how to select by content if it contains alphanumeric chars?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first working example should read:

    `xml sel -t -c "/metainfo[timestamp=1385742689568] test.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote string values, otherwise it looks for a tag with name `asdf`. Also, you have to use [normalize-space()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) to ignore leading and trailing whitespace:

```
xml sel -t -c "/metabundle/metainfo[normalize-space(name)='asdf']" test.xml
```

Comment: Perfect! I know that string values like to be quoted, but this was not the reason :)>> normalize-space(name) << That did the trick! Thank you!